# convert Swift 2.3 to Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, cgrect, uiedgeinsets

I am new in Swift 4 and I want to resolve the Swift version 2.0 Project with Uitextview error

here is error in Swift 4

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectInset(view.bounds, 10, 10))
```

I will change with **'CGRectInset' has been replaced by instance method 'CGRect.insetBy(dx:dy:)'**

but I don't know how

I change with let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.insetBy(view.bounds, 10, 10)) but error again

and here is other problem

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

I will change the `UIEdgeInsetsZero`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: view.bounds.insetBy(dx:10,dy:10))
```

Comment: now I received Extra argument in call for last 10